# Oracle 11 SQL : Is there a way to split 1 row into x rows

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

Customer asked to Split 1 row from the Oracle DB SQL into 6 rows.

Let's say, originally the SQL (complex sql with multiple joins , etc) is pulling in 9 columns:
select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I  from X, Y, Z . . .  (but quite complex query)

1) A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I.

Now, customer is asking for every row returning above pattern, the new output should be like below :
1) A, B, C, 'D', D
2) A, B, C, 'E', E
3) A, B, C, 'F', F
4) A, B, C, 'G', G
5) A, B, C, 'H', H
6) A, B, C, 'I', I

Basically, the 1st 3 columns will be repeated in all the 6 NEW ROWS.
The procedure repeats for every row in the original query.

Is this possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Is A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H column_names or actual values

Comment: they are values pulled together from various tables

Comment: Its a bit unclear, can you provide the column_names and the values

Comment: It is possible, with the `unpivot` operator (the most efficient way; there are other ways too). If what you show is the result of a complex query, that doesn't matter; treat it all as a subquery (perhaps in a `with` clause). But, the bigger question is, if the "big query" with joins and whatnot gives the result in a format which is not the required format, why is the big query written that way in the first place? There may be much more efficient ways to get the desired result **directly**, not by unpivoting the result you have so far.

Comment: @mathguy : The original request was the big query with joins, etc. Then, after we delivered the project, customer asked for chagne --- don't know why customer asked for change. Could you pls. answer with unpivot operator please ? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need `unpivot` clause to show the data vertically :

```
with t(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) as
(
 select 1,2,3,'D','E',2,3,'X','Y' from dual 
)
select a,b,c,val from
(
select a,b,c,to_char(d) as d, to_char(e) as e, to_char(f) as f, to_char(g) as g, 
             to_char(h) as h, to_char(i) as i
  from t
)  
unpivot 
( val for col in (d,e,f,g,h,i) )
order by col
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f2fac3c421caa8259360b1271b97cec)</kbd>

**to_char()** conversions are implemented against getting **ORA-01790:** *expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression* error.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, Thanks.   A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I are not strings/characters. Some of them are strings and some of them are numbers, etc. Can you rework your SQL please ?

Comment: hm well, you need to consider unpivot clause, then. you're welcome @anjanb

Comment: Hi @Barbaros Özhan, thank you. You answered my question. I have another very related question to this  -- please answer that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59244741/oracle-11-sql-split-1-row-into-x-rows-and-insert-a-new-column

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest using `union all`:

```
select a, b, c, 'D' as which, d as val from t union all
select a, b, c, 'E', e from t union all
select a, b, c, 'F', f from t union all
select a, b, c, 'G', g from t union all
select a, b, c, 'H', j from t union all
select a, b, c, 'I', i from t ;
```

This is the *simplest* way, but not the most efficient.  It will scan the table once for each column.  For not-too-large table, that is probably fine (the table is cached in memory) from a performance perspective.

If the "table", though" is really a view, then performance could be a more significant issue.

Comment: thanks. This is the simplest and obvious. Since this query returns about half a million rows, it would be preferable to have a more efficient means. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @anjanb . . . Actually, on that volume of data, it probably doesn't make a difference.  The table will be loaded into memory after the first scan and the subsequent scans would then be very fast.

Comment: there're multiple such queries going on in the DB concurrently. I doubt the DB will load only this query's results into RAM given there are bigger resultsets from the other queries. I will test it anyways and share my results.